# Java volatile for concurrency

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile

Ok so I just read this question [Do you ever use the volatile keyword in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106591/do-you-ever-use-the-volatile-keyword-in-java), and I get using a volatile variable in order to stop a loop. Also I've seen this reference, http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml. Now the article says that volatile variables are non-blocking. Also it says that it cannot be used for concurrency in a read-update-write sequence. Which makes sense because they're non-blocking.

Since volatile variables are never cached is it faster to simply use synchronization to stop the loop (from the earlier link)?

Edit: Using a synchronized solution

```
public class A{
  private boolean test;

  public A(){
    test = true;
  }

  public synchronized void stop(){
    test = false;
  }

  public synchronized boolean isTrue(){
    return test;
  }
}

public class B extends Thread {
  private A a;

  public B(A refA){
    a = refA;
  }

  public void run(){
    //Does stuff here
    try{
      sleep(1000);
    }
    catch(Exception e){}
    a.stop();
  }

  public static void main(String [] args){
    A TestA = new A();
    B TestB = new B(TestA);
    TestB.start();
    while(TestA.isTrue()){
      //stay in loop
      System.out.println("still in loop");
    }
    System.out.println("Done with loop");
  }
 }
```

Comment: What loop are you talking about? Please include an example of your proposed usage of `synchronized` in the question.

Comment: Goto the first link I posted and look for the highest rated answer.

Comment: your expecting a lot of your readers.  Next time, just include the example in the question ...

Comment: I did look at that answer, but it describes the correct use of `volatile`. I wanted you to provide an example of how you'd use `synchronized` instead, so that I could give more specific advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, reading a `volatile` variable is faster than than reading an non-`volatile` variable in a `synchronized` block.

A `synchronized` block clears the cached values on entry which is the same as reading a `volatile` variable. *But,* it also flushes any cached writes to main memory when the synchronized block is exited, which isn't necessary when reading `volatile` variable.

Comment: Caches are not flushed and main memory doesn't need to be involved at all. 

In case of an unlock and volatile write, the CPU stops issuing loads till the store buffer has been drained. If the cache line of the write isn't in MODIFIED or EXCLUSIVE state, a Request for Ownership is done to invalidate the cache line in other caches and once that is granted, the write can complete to the L1D cache.

Cache lines can live in caches indefinitely. Apart from capacity reasons, there is no reason to write a cache line to main memory... ever...

Answer (score 2):

There's a numebr of things wrong in your question: You can do a reliable read-update-write with `volatile` so long as you use `Atomic*FieldUpdater` and a cas-loop. Volatiles can be "cached", they just need to obey the relevant *happens-before* semantics specified.

Synchronisation typically involves obtaining a lock, which is relatively expensive (although may actually be quite cheap). Simple concurrent optimisations may use non-naive implementation techniques.

Comment: After looking at the article again from Java 5 onwards it's possible